# Ports and Addresses

Tags: networking, port, ip-address

I have a simple question

What is the difference between :

```
172.16.0.0/16
```

and

```
172.16.0.0:16
```

I have done some research and cant find the answer

Any help would be great. thanks

Comment: `/16`is a subnet and `:16` is a port.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But why downvote, I am very new obviously to this topic and just trying to learn?

Comment: IP addresses are network-layer addresses, but ports are addresses for _some_ transport-layer protocols, e.g. TCP and UDP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

/16 is a subnet and :16 is a port.